# Если Google Play приложение имеет ссылку на бесплатную свою ДЕМО-версию, нужно ли ставить галочку Да, есть реклама (в приложении)?

Tags: android, google-play, реклама

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я поставлю Да, то получается, что приложение объявят как имеющее рекламу (что есть не айс) всего-лишь за одну ссылку на свою бесплатную Демо версию...

Что делать пока не пойму... )

Comment: в описании размещать или где именно?

Comment: В самом приложении!

Comment: Странный вопрос. GP же не запрещает рекламу в приложениях.

Comment: D-side, я пояснил ситуацию в вопросе...

Comment: Признаться, что рекламируете другие свои приложения, например. Да, это реклама.

Comment: @D-side, спасибо! Даже ссылка на бесплатную Демо-версию данного (текущего) приложения есть уже реклама???

Comment: К работе нынешнего приложения это не имеет никакого отношения, так что да, можно назвать рекламой.